# PDF from content of asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I'm trying to create a pdf of the content on a page ("returnsPage.aspx?id="returnId) and allow the user to download this directly when clicking the button.

However in my onClick method I have the following code:

```
lnkLoadPDF.CommandArgument = "/returns/returnsPage.aspx?id="+returnId.ToString(); 
string virtualPath = lnkLoadPDF.CommandArgument;
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(virtualPath);

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.WriteFile(virtualPath);
Response.ContentType = "";
Response.End();
Response.Redirect("/returns/returnsPage.aspx?id="+returnId);
```

which returns this error:

> '/returns/returnsPage.aspx?id=23' is not a valid virtual path.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a build error or a runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to turn a webpage into a pdf, you must convert it to pdf on the server.  In order to do that, you must have a [program on the server](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) that can do that for you.

I've tried a variety of webpage-to-pdf converters and one of the better ones is a free, open source program called [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

After you create the pdf, you can either redirect the user to the newly created pdf (discouraged), or [prompt them to download it with a savefile dialog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET).

If you get stuck, just search for wkhtmltopdf on stackoverflow or post another question.

Comment: thanks I'm going to try this. Sorry if my question was too simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send a file to the client *and* redirect him to a new location during the same request. You also can't create a PDF from a webpage without some kind of component that converts the HTML into a PDF, it's (quite a bit) more tricky that what I think you're trying to attempt.

As for your exception, are you sure returnsPage.aspx exists? :)